# Using super() for equals() in a subclass in a different package

Tags: java, inheritance, compilation, nullpointerexception, package

I have a class Vehicle which is in package A and a class Car which is in package B and I want to use equals method and take advantage of inheritance by using super(), but I don't know how to do this.

When I try to run the file in main I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at vehicle.Vehicle.equals(Vehicle.java:97)
    at car.Car.equals(Car.java:104)
    at Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

Here is the code:

```
public boolean equals(Vehicle other) {
    if (this.type.equals(other.type)) {
        if (this.year == other.year && this.price == other.price) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
//equals in Car
public boolean equals(Car other) {
    if (this.type.equals(other.type)) {
        if (this.speed == other.speed && this.door == other.door) {
            if (super.equals(other)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `instanceof` to check instance types.

Comment: Note that you haven't overriden the `equals` method, but overloaded it. `equals` method takes an `Object` as argument.

Comment: @RohitJain Excellent Point out.

Comment: if I use Object, the equals() method don't work because the class vehicle is in a package and its variable has the default access right, which means only classes in the package can access it.

Comment: @prog: can you put codes of `Vehicle` and `Car` class?

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` method as per [the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) should return `false` when `null` passed as an argument:

> For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Add this at the very beginning of every `equals()` method:

```
if(other == null) {
  return false;
}
```

Secondly you have to override `equals()`, not overload it:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

Finally you'll need `instanceof` and downcasting to make this all work.

And BTW this:

```
if (this.speed == other.speed && this.door == other.door)
{
    if(super.equals(other))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (this.speed == other.speed && this.door == other.door)
{
    return super.equals(other);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

which in turns can be reduced to:

```
return this.speed == other.speed && this.door == other.door && super.equals(other);
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: constant.equals(variable). +1

Comment: @Legend not really rull of thumb since that can be sometimes wrong

Comment: I think the reason why I get null is because type is null, because type is in another package and it isn't public and I can't access it since the access right is default.

Comment: object doesn't have access to speed and door variables

Comment: @prog: indeed, that' why I said "*you'll need instanceof and downcasting to make this all work*"